# Recursive ZIP won't work in zsh

Tags: command-line, zip

Until catalina I used

```
zip -r xmp.zip . -i *.xmp
```

To add all xmp files from subdirectories to xmp.zip. Upgraded to mojave (zsh) and now it won't work anymore (return no matches found). How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote or escape the "include" pattern `*.xmp` to keep the shell from trying to expand it into a list of files in the current directory. You want the shell to just pass it to `zip` so that the zip program can use it as a pattern to match files in the current directory *and subdirectories*. Any of these will work:

```
zip -r xmp.zip . -i \*.xmp
zip -r xmp.zip . -i "*.xmp"
zip -r xmp.zip . -i '*.xmp'
```

This is described in the zip man page:

> `-i` files
> `--include` files
> Include only the specified files, as in:
>
> ```
>                 zip -r foo . -i \*.c
> ```
>
> [...] The backslash avoids the shell filename substitution,  so  that  the  name  matching  is performed by zip at all directory levels. [...]

This will not have caused an error under bash, because bash just leaves wildcard patterns alone if they don't match any files; zsh, on the other hand, treats this as an error.

Note that you really should have been quoting or escaping the pattern under bash as well. If you ever used that command without quoting/escaping, and there *were* .xmp files in the current directory... then the resulting zip archives may not contain what you expect them to.

Comment: For any shell the * and ? are computed as a list of matching files before the execution of the command. So doing ‘myCommand *.x’ is interpreted as ´myCommand file1.x file2.x …’ by the shell.